# JMETER - Populate a JSON request for all items in an array

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I am pretty new to testing with JMeter.  I have a JSON block that I would like to populate with values from three arrays that I created from a previous GET request.  The structure is similar to this:

```
    "books": [
        {
            "publisher": ${publisherName}, //variable but it's the same for all items in this request
            "ISBN": ${isbn_1},  //the next three are from from 3 different arrays 
            "Price": ${price_1},
            "Publisher": ${publisher_1},
            "Static Value that doesn't change": 100
       
        },

        {
            "publisher": ${publisherName}, //variable but it's the same for all items in this request
            "ISBN": ${isbn_2},  //the next three are from from 3 different arrays 
            "Price": ${price_2},
            "Publisher": ${publisher_2},
            "Static Value that will be the same for all items": 100
       
        },
        
    ],
```

Is there a way to loop through adding the blocks dynamically so I can send all of these items in a single request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [any suitable JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language

Without seeing how your "arrays" look like it's hard to come up with a comprehensive solution, the JSON structure can be created like:

```
vars.put('publisherName', 'some publisher')
vars.put('isbn_1', 'foo')
vars.put('isbn_2', 'bar')
vars.put('price_1', '123')
vars.put('price_2', '456')
vars.put('publisher_1', 'baz')
vars.put('publisher_2', 'qux')


def arraySize = vars.entrySet().findAll { entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith('isbn_') }.size()

def books = []

1.upto(arraySize, {index ->
    books.add([publisher:vars.get('publisherName'),
               ISBN: vars.get('isbn_' + index),
               Price: vars.get('price_' + index),
               Publisher:vars.get('publisher_' + index),
               "Static Value that doesn't change": 100
    ])
})

log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([books:books]).toPrettyString())
```

[image]

The generated value can be stored into a JMeter Variable like:

```
vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([books:books]).toPrettyString())
```

and used as `${payload}` later on where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: The arrays are JMeter variables that are created using the JSON Extractor in a previous step.  Each of the arrays are the same size containing 140 different values each.  

Can I reference the JMeter arrays in the Groovy script?  Such as ${isbn_1} ${isbn_2} etc?

Comment: You can using `vars` shorthand like in my above example: `def isbn = vars.get('isbn_1')`. It stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for other JMeter API shorthands. Don't refer variables like `${isbn_1}` because [only first value will be cached and used on next iterations](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have 3 different arrays with same size for `ISBN`, `Price`, `Publisher`. You write code to `JSR223 Pre-Processor`

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def books = []

def isbn_list = ['isbn1', 'isbn2', 'isbn3']
def price_list = [100, 200, 300]
def publisher_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def publisher = "fix"

for (i = 0; i < isbn_list.size(); i++) {
    def book = [:]
    book['publisher'] = publisher
    book['ISBN'] = isbn_list[i]
    book['Price'] = price_list[i]
    book['Publisher'] = publisher_list[i]
    books.add(book)
}

vars.put('books', JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(books)))
```

[image]

Comment: The arrays are JMeter variables that are created using the JSON Extractor in a previous step. Each of the arrays are the same size containing 140 different values each. Can I reference the JMeter arrays in the Groovy script? Such as ${isbn_1} ${isbn_2} etc?