# JMETER - Formatting JSON with JsonBuilder

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

Hello I previously asked how to dynamically generate a json array using Groovy here:

[JMETER - Populate a JSON request for all items in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76569179/jmeter-populate-a-json-request-for-all-items-in-an-array)

The provided solution worked great, however I need to add an additional object after the final item in the array.  Because the toprettystring formats the array I am unsure how to insert the  object into the final result.

Here is an example of the final JSON:

```
{
 "books": [
        {
            "publisher": ${publisherName}, //variable but it's the same for all items in this request
            "ISBN": ${isbn_1},  //the next three are from from 3 different arrays 
            "Price": ${price_1},
            "Publisher": ${publisher_1},
            "Static Value that doesn't change": 100
       
        },

        {
            "publisher": ${publisherName}, //variable but it's the same for all items in this request
            "ISBN": ${isbn_2},  //the next three are from from 3 different arrays 
            "Price": ${price_2},
            "Publisher": ${publisher_2},
            "Static Value that will be the same for all items": 100
       
        },
        
    ],
    "meta": {
        "tag": {
            "searchNumber": ${searchNo}
        }
    }
}
```

The solution for the previous question was to use a JSR223 Preprocessor and generate it as follows:

```
def arraySize = vars.entrySet().findAll { entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith('isbn_') }.size()

def books = []

1.upto(arraySize, {index ->
    books.add([publisher:vars.get('publisherName'),
               ISBN: vars.get('isbn_' + index),
               Price: vars.get('price_' + index),
               Publisher:vars.get('publisher_' + index),
               "Static Value that doesn't change": 100
    ])
})

log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([books:books]).toPrettyString())
```

How could I modify this to enter the above object into the final JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your final result formed here:

```
log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([books:books]).toPrettyString())
```

just add required fields into this map: `[books:books]`

for example instead of last line:

```js
def searchNo = ...
def result=[
    books: books,
    meta: [
        tag: [searchNumber: searchNo]
    ]
]
log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(result).toPrettyString())
```

Comment: This works, however now I'm runing into an issue where my JMeter variable is being formatted with quotation marks.  the tag should be  "searchNumber": 27007, but is being formatted as "searchNumber":"27007"  I'm using vars.get('searchNo') to pull the JMeter variable.

Comment: it really depends on value type. 1/ don't put it in quotes: `[searchNumber: searchNo]` 2/ if 1 is not working `[searchNumber: searchNo as Integer]`

Answer (score 1):

Amend your code as follows:

```
def arraySize = vars.entrySet().findAll { entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith('isbn_') }.size()

def request = [:]

def books = []

1.upto(arraySize, { index ->
    books.add([publisher                         : vars.get('publisherName'),
               ISBN                              : vars.get('isbn_' + index),
               Price                             : vars.get('price_' + index),
               Publisher                         : vars.get('publisher_' + index),
               "Static Value that doesn't change": 100
    ])
})

def meta = [tag: [searchNumber: vars.getObject('searchNo')]]
request.put('books', books)
request.put('meta', meta)
log.info((new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(request).toPrettyString()))
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)